Will an HDMI DM or HDBASET connection work extended over a fiber ethernet adapter?
I have a long run to get a 4k video signal from a podium to a pojector (over the 300ft distance limit of Cat6). Will an HDBASE-T or DM HDMI CAT6 extender work with a pair of ethernet to fiber adpters in the middle? My thought is that the fiber to ethernet adpter Should just extend the connection for a long run, but the signal is video and not a network connection, strictly speaking. Has anyone tried this or had experience attempting? What is the outcome?
I could just buy all the hardware and test, but I am tying to avoid that, especially if it won't work. Any and all input is appreciated.

Have you considered any of the existing fiber optic HDMI extenders on the market? I see a pair on Amazon that claims 4K @ 10km for US$400 for the pair, fiber cable sold separately.

I suspect it won't work.
The adapter (media converter) does not directly wire the copper Ethernet to the fiber laser/LED – it has to fully terminate the Ethernet connection on both sides and only forward the data bits between the two, which makes it specific to the Ethernet physical layer.
Keep in mind, in Gigabit or 10Gbit Ethernet there are four data pairs on the copper side but only one color on the fiber side. So the adapter needs to specifically understand the signalling that copper Ethernet uses (e.g. PAM-5 plus whatever else goes on top of it), decode the received bits, then send them over fiber using different signalling… and that's after it negotiates Gigabit Ethernet mode on the copper side, which requires even more Ethernet-specific communications.
And the signalling used by copper Ethernet is not entirely the same as the one used by HDBaseT – although 10Gbit Ethernet seems to be similar, they still run at different bit rates, perform different processing on the signal, etc., so an Ethernet media converter can neither transmit nor receive it.
(It seems that the HDBaseT specification includes provisions for dual-mode devices that can also talk standard Ethernet, but from what I'm reading, it would only switch to a pure Ethernet mode, using it only as a plain network connection but not sending any HDMI data over it.)
As far as I know, DM (non "Lite") is HDBaseT so everything applies to it as well (and the same likely goes for DM-Lite too, which is so proprietary that I couldn't find any information about its physical layer).
